# Why there are so many !important rules in jqgrid css?

Tags: css, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid-4.5.4. I want to apply my application's theme on jqgrid, hence trying to override some css like below & many more :

```
Original :
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hdiv {
    border-left: 0 none !important;
    border-right: 0 none !important;
    border-top: 0 none !important;
    margin:     
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
My theme :
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hdiv {
    border: 1px solid #dedede; 
}
```

But because of the !important rules in many places in ui.jqgrid.css I'm not able to not edit the original jqgrid's css file.

Query 1. Why does the css file contain so many !important rules ?

Query 2. My idea was to keep the original file as it is and have the overriding css in a separate file, so when I upgrade jqgrid it'll be easier to go through only the changes in my theme file and update it, rather than finding difference between the old and new jqgrid'css file.
Am I the one who is doing it like this or any other ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello. I think you can just create an other css, overriding these values like you did, and put the call to your css before the call of the jqgrid css. put your css values in !important too, or it will be override by jqgrid.

But doing this, with a lot of !important isn't really good... just remove them from jqgrid if you don't want to be upset, but take care, it could change some things

EDIT: put a longer path that the one provided in jqgrid if you can, it's always better

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was also wondering the reason for those !important rules, hence I would know if I can remove them or should find a different way of overriding them, like you suggestion.

Comment: I think that removing these !important can be dangerous for your style, but if they did that, it is certainly to remove some "bug" in their code or simply don't let the user change them. Just have a try, changing the border isn't so dangerous ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I override several jQGrid CSS rules in my code.

Simply include your own Custom CSS file **AFTER** you include the jQGrid CSS file and use `!important`.

Include example:

```
<!-- jQGrid CSS -->
<link href="Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- My Custom CSS Included AFTER the jQGrid CSS -->
<link href="Content/global.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And Inside my custom CSS file, I have rules such as:

```
.navtable .ui-pg-button .ui-pg-div {
    margin: 0 8px 0 8px !important;
}
```

This will override the jQGrid default style since it's in my custom CSS file, included **AFTER** the jQGrid CSS file.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it will work for me. But still I'm left curious why those rules have to be !important in the first place in ui.jqgrid.css :(

Comment: @code.tweetie I'm not 100% sure why they added the `!important` flag on most of their styles. I'm thinking it's to prevent any interference with other plugins that might also use the same classes/IDs. Also, if this question helped you, please [**accept**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :-)

Comment: The reason I just upvoted & didnt accept was because my original question is still unanswered.

Comment: @code.tweetie You want a definitive answer as to why the creator(s) of jQGrid put so many `!important` flags in the CSS file? I doubt you will ever get that answered, at least not here on SO (none of us know, unless one of us is a jQGrid creator)... you'll need to post on the Trirand forums and maybe, possibly have one of the developers tell you why they used it so many times. Although, what will you even do with that knowledge, if you actually do get someone to tell you why? Just so you know for your own sanity? lol